# Pipe data to redis

Tags: redis, pipe

When I pipe the echo to redis client, I get an error.

```
[root@server ~]$ echo "abc43345" | redis-cli set my_passwd2
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command
```

But the following works as expected.

```
[root@server ~]$ redis-cli set my_passwd2 `echo "abc43345"`
OK
```

Is there any way to make the first example work?

Comment: `redis-cli` is expecting an argument on the command line, not on `stdin`. The way to do this with a lot of other command line apps is to specify a dash `-`, signifying that that command line parameter should be read from `stdin`. I don't know if `redis-cli` supports that, and don't have it installed right now to check.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It can actually be achieved using "-x" flag

`echo "abc43345" | redis-cli -x set my_passwd2`